# Is it possible to specify a value of a generic type whose type parameter conforms to the original constraints in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, types

Recently, I came across the following problem in Swift.

EDIT: Here's a more concrete example. We're trying to make a challenge service, where the user is presented with a series of random challenges.

```
protocol PreferencesProtocol: Codable {
    var backgroundColorHex: String? { get set };
    init();
}
class Preferences: PreferencesProtocol {
  var backgroundColorHex: String?;
  required init() {
    instantSuccessFeedback = true;
    backgroundColorHex = "#FFFFFF";
  }
}
class ExerciseDescription<PreferencesType: Preferences>: ExerciseDescriptionProtocol {
  static var preferencesType: PreferencesType.Type {
    return PreferencesType.self;
  }

  class var internalName: String {
    get{
      fatalError("\(String(describing: type(of: self)))Exercise must have a unique internal name");
    }
  }
  // Will be overridden
  class func getViewController(initialPreferences: PreferencesType) -> ExerciseViewController<PreferencesType> {
    return ExerciseViewController<PreferencesType>(initialPreferences: initialPreferences);
  }

  private init() {}
}
```

And we have some exercise Matching with preferences and description

```
class MatchingPreferences: Preferences {
  var cardCount: Int = 5;
}

class MatchingDescription: ExerciseDescription<MatchingPreferences> {
  typealias PreferenceType = MatchingPreferences;
  override class func getViewController(initialPreferences: MatchingPreferences) -> ExerciseViewController<MatchingPreferences> {
    return MatchingViewController(initialPreferences: initialPreferences);
  }
  override class var internalName: String{
    return "matching";
  }
}
```

And we want to store the upcoming exercises in a scheduler service:

```
struct FakeScheduleService {
  static var currentExerciseDescriptions: [ExerciseDescription<Preferences>.Type] {
    return [MatchingDescription.self]
  }
  static var nextExerciseDescription: ExerciseDescription<Preferences>.Type {
    return MatchingDescription.self;
  }

  static var rewardDuration: Int {
    return 200;
  }
}
```

The idea is to be able to create these preference objects from JSON objects and then launch exercises on a schedule, while not forcing exercises to force cast their preferences.

Comment: We can do better if we know your goal with these generics

Comment: @tereks The idea is to make a series of exercise views, which take their own parameters and are presented from a central scheduling service. So that exercise subclasses don't have to cast their preferences, there is a generic that sets the types for them. The preferences would all subclass some object that conforms to Codable and has an init with no parameters (for defaults). The scheduling service would then contain the array of exercises and launch them (initially) from their defaults, and after that, from values saved to disk (retrieved from internet). I'll update the question.

Comment: Is the array literal (`[RestaurantPatron<SomeOtherPreferences>.self]`) intentional?

Comment: @Alexander yes, although the declared type of the variable may not have been correct. I've created a more concrete example.

Comment: @tereks I've edited the question to be more specific and show intent

Comment: @zefre I don't see any necessity for ExerciseDescription to be generic. Why don't you consider having var preferences:  Preferences in ExerciseDescription class, instead of generics

Comment: @tereks It seems like at that point, we'd be storing a value instead of a type, and the goal is to serialize/deserialize the preferences to/from JSON. I could use Preferences.Type, but then the ExerciseViewController would have to cast from Preferences.